# Creating an Address Locator with a Database of Geo Information

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, geocoding, mysql, address

I am trying to build an Address Locator for ArcGIS 10.1. I would like to use a Microsoft Server MySQL database where location information is stored using an alias, an address, and XY coordinates. What is the best way to create a geocoding service using this setup?

An option I have considered is writing a script to dump the SQL database into a format that plays well with ArcGIS on a regular basis but wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a white paper I have found useful for working with custom Locators in the past.

http://egis3.lacounty.gov/eGIS/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Customizing-Locators-in-ArcGIS-10.pdf